# How to create a population density heatmap from attributes

Tags: qgis, point, style, heat-map, density

I'm working with a point shapefile representing the municipalities of a country. Each point has an attribute that shows the population of the given municipality. Is it possible to map this attribute by a heatmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS, you may try to follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the layer loaded in the Layers Panel;
2. Go to `Properties >> Style`;
3. Choose `Heatmap`;
4. Define the field to use for the heatmap (and the eventual other parameters).

Comment: In what software??? It is not indicated in the tags.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans sorry, I assumed the OP was using QGIS and I properly edited my answer. Since the OP accepted it, I probably was right.

Comment: @mgri - What I normally do when OP hasn't mentioned a tag for the software they're using, I become a temporary stalker and check their previous questions. Sometimes it works :)

Comment: @Joseph very nice idea! :)